# How to extend Throttle Timespan in middle of a long running query?

Tags: c#, system.reactive, reactive-programming

Is it possible to extend Throttle Timespan value in middle of a query? For instance, assuming an example as in [101 Rx Samples Throttle](http://rxwiki.wikidot.com/101samples#toc30) there is this query `var throttled = observable.Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(750));`.

What if I wanted to change it so that if during the first 500 ms there will be no events, then the throttling value would be extended to, e.g., 1500 ms for every event thereafter.

Would this be a place to use the `Switch` operator?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an overload of `Throttle` that accepts a factory function that takes the source event and produces a "throttle stream" that is an `IObservable<T>` (T can be any type). Events will be suppressed until the throttle stream emits.

The following example has a stream that pumps every second, with a throttle factory producing a 0.5 second throttle. Thus at start, the source stream is not throttled.

If you enter say, 2, the throttle will change to a two second throttle and all events will be suppressed. Change down to 1 and events will appear again.

```
void Main()
{
    var throttleDuration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5);
    Func<long, IObservable<long>> throttleFactory =
        _ => Observable.Timer(throttleDuration);

    var sequence = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
                             .Throttle(throttleFactory);

    var subscription = sequence.Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);

    string input = null;
    Console.WriteLine("Enter throttle duration in seconds or q to quit");
    while(input != "q")
    {       
        input = Console.ReadLine().Trim().ToLowerInvariant();
        double duration;

        if(input == "q") break;
        if(!double.TryParse(input, out duration))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Eh?");
            continue;
        }
        throttleDuration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(duration);
    }

    subscription.Dispose();
    Console.WriteLine("Done");
}
```

Because this is a factory function producing the throttle per event, you can create something much more dynamic that returns a throttle stream based on the particular input event.

The idea of a stream used as a control like this is a very common technique used throughout the Rx API and is well worth wrapping your head around: examples of similar uses include the `other` argument to `TakeUntil`, the `durationSelector` in `GroupByUntil`, the `bufferClosingSelector` in `Buffer`.

Comment: Hmm, how come I didn't see that factory function..? For the record, I became to wonder this example from a functional perspective as a change of state, which could be tricky. Well, it turned out to be easier than I imagined. I'll take a look at these. It maybe this even simplifies the alarm example you quite helpfully provided example code for. Cheers again!