# How can I combine IObservable<T>.Throttle() with some other event source using Reactive Extensions?

Tags: c#, linq, system.reactive, reactive-programming

I have a simple search field which should search automatically after the user has stopped typing or when he presses *Search*. The first part can be easily achieved with the following

```
var inputs = Observable.FromEventPattern<SomeEventArgs>(searchBar, "TextChanged")
                       .Select(pattern => pattern.EventArgs.SearchText)
                       .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500));
```

I can also chain that to do the actual search like this

```
var results = from query in inputs
              from results in Observable.FromAsync<Something>(() => Search(query))
              select results;
```

But the problem is that there is no way to *skip ahead* when the user presses the search button. From my understanding of Rx the code should probably be something like this:

```
// inputs = the same event stream without Throttle
// buttonClicks = construct event stream for search button clicks

// ??? somehow make a third stream which lets a value through
// ??? only after a delay and when the value hasn't changed,
// ??? OR when the second stream yields a value

// async search
```

I can see how I would write this imperatively by using something like `Stopwatch` and resetting it as the user types, and if a click comes through I could just skip it over. But in the world of Rx it would probably look like (pardon the pseudo-linq-code)

```
from query in inputs
where (query.isLast() and query.timestamp > 500.ms.ago) or buttonClicked
...
```

**I need to be able to get through the last query input immediately if the second event source yields a value, or if there is no value then just wait a specified delay as if Throttle is used**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, the typical search Rx looks like this:

```
var searchResults = Observable.FromEventPattern<SomeEventArgs>(searchBar, "TextChanged")
                              .Select(pattern => pattern.EventArgs.SearchText)
                              .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500))
                              .DistinctUntilChanged()
                              .Select(text => Observable.Start(() => Search(text)))
                              .Switch()
```

Select gives you a stream of result streams, Switch will return the most recently created stream. I added DistinctUntilChanged to prevent duplicate queries being submitted.

One strategy for what you have described is to supply the throttle a throttle duration selector that will emit either after the throttle duration or if a button is clicked. I've knocked together a sample ViewModel that avoids using any libraries other than Rx 2.1 to show how this might be done. This is the whole ViewModel - I'll leave the View and Repository to your imagination, but it should be clear what they do.

Final caveat - I've tried to keep this sample brief and leave out unnecessary details that might cloud understanding so this isn't production ready:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Reactive;
using System.Reactive.Linq;
using System.Reactive.Subjects;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Windows.Input;
using StackOverflow.Rx.Annotations;
using StackOverflow.Rx.Model;

namespace StackOverflow.Rx.ProductSearch
{
    public class ClassicProductSearchViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _query;
        private IProductRepository _productRepository;
        private IList<Product> _productSearchResults;

        public ClassicProductSearchViewModel(IProductRepository productRepository)
        {
            _productRepository = productRepository;
            // Wire up a Button from the view to this command with a binding like
            // <Button Content="Search" Command="{Binding ImmediateSearch}"/>
            ImmediateSearch = new ReactiveCommand();

            // Wire up the Query text from the view with
            // a binding like <TextBox MinWidth="100" Text="{Binding Query, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            var newQueryText = Observable.FromEventPattern<PropertyChangedEventHandler, PropertyChangedEventArgs>(
                h => PropertyChanged += h,
                h => PropertyChanged -= h)
                .Where(@event => @event.EventArgs.PropertyName == "Query")
                .Select(_ => Query);

            // This duration selector will emit EITHER after the delay OR when the command executes
            var throttleDurationSelector = Observable.Return(Unit.Default)
                                                     .Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2))
                                                     .Merge(ImmediateSearch.Select(x => Unit.Default));


            newQueryText
                .Throttle(x => throttleDurationSelector)
                .DistinctUntilChanged()
                /* Your search query here */
                .Select(
                    text =>
                        Observable.StartAsync(
                            () => _productRepository.FindProducts(new ProductNameStartsWithSpecification(text))))
                .Switch()
                .ObserveOnDispatcher()
                .Subscribe(products => ProductSearchResults = new List<Product>(products));
        }

        public IList<Product> ProductSearchResults
        {
            get { return _productSearchResults; }
            set
            {
                if (Equals(value, _productSearchResults)) return;
                _productSearchResults = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public ReactiveCommand ImmediateSearch { get; set; }

        public string Query
        {
            get { return _query; }
            set
            {
                if (value == _query) return;
                _query = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    // A command that is also an IObservable!
    public class ReactiveCommand : ICommand, IObservable<object>
    {
        private bool _canExecute = true;
        private readonly Subject<object> _execute = new Subject<object>();

        public ReactiveCommand(IObservable<bool> canExecute = null)
        {
            if (canExecute != null)
            {
                canExecute.Subscribe(x => _canExecute = x);
            }
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return _canExecute;
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            _execute.OnNext(parameter);
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

        public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<object> observer)
        {
            return _execute.Subscribe(observer);
        }
    }
}
```

There are libraries out there like Rxx and ReactiveUI that can make this code simpler - I've not used them here so there is minimal "magic" going on!

My ReactiveCommand in this example is a simple implementation of one included in ReactiveUI. This looks like a command and an IObservable at the same time. Whenever it is executed it will stream the command parameter.

Here is an example using ReactiveUI from the author's blog: http://blog.paulbetts.org/index.php/2010/06/22/reactivexaml-series-reactivecommand/

[In another answer I look at the variable throttling feature in isolation.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19499469/how-to-extend-throttle-timespan-in-middle-of-a-long-running-query/19505431#19505431)

Comment: Added a large sample that properly addresses the requirement to immediately execute the search on a button press.

Comment: FYI - signature for the query function I am using is: `Task<IEnumerable<Product>> FindProducts(SpecificationBase<Product> specification);`

Comment: Thanks for a great solution! I have one problem with it though. I'm using Rx for Xamarin and I don't seem to have the `.Switch()` method, but I've solved this with a `SelectMany()` and it works just fine :) **But I still don't understand the throttleDuractionSelector**, how does the `Delay` call know when to start counting?

Comment: The throttle subscribes to the durationSelector (starting the delay) *on each event* - if the durationSelector OnNext's or OnComplete's before the next event comes in, the throttle OnNext's.